# Where to store external images Intellij GWT Projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, project-structure

I'm using Intellij and GWT, I created a GWT project and Intellij has automatically created the directory structure. I have then tried to add an external image, however I am getting a 404 when trying to retrieve the image.

Project structure is below:

project 
 -- .idea 
 -- out 
 -- src 
 ---- com.project 
 -------- client 
-------- server 
 -------- project.gwt.xml 
 -- web 
 ---- images 
 -------- myimage.png 
 ---- WEB-INF 
 ---- project.css 
 ---- project.html

I am setting the image URL with:

img.setUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "images/myimage.png");

I have read a few similar issues saying it need to be placed within an images folder within the war folder, however with intellij it has not generated a war folder, just the web folder, so I am thinking my issue may be around this.

I had no problems doing the same thing when using GWT with Eclipse however I now have to use Intellij.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
img.setUrl("images/myimage.png");
```

`web` folder is not related to GWT modules - it's the same for the entire app.